# Knockout extender notification fires multiple times

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout extender to check weather my observable value is changed or not ? it's working fine , I am getting the notification when there is a change in my observable. But why it's notifying me multiple times. You keep on typing in the input you can see number of notifications increases in the console ? if I type in 3 letters then knockout should notify me 3 times why it's notifying me 20 times?

My html

```
<div id="mydivhtml"> 
   <input type="text" data-bind="value:$root.Message.extend({ trackMessage: 'xyx'}),valueUpdate : 'afterkeydown'"/>
</div>
```

My Js

```
function MyViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.Message = ko.observable("");

    ko.extenders.trackMessage = function (target, message) {

        target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            console.log('message Changed');
        });

        return target;
    };
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel(), $('#mydivhtml')[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value binding is incorrect, it should contain only the value observable, the one you put will activate the trackMessage extender everytime you input and will have multiple subscription, thus the multiple execution.

Just change your html to this one.

```
<div id="mydivhtml"> 
   <input type="text" data-bind="value:$root.Message, valueUpdate : 'afterkeydown'"/>
</div>
```

And your view model to this one:

```
function MyViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.Message = ko.observable("");

    ko.extenders.trackMessage = function (target, message) {

        target.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            console.log('message Changed');
         });

         return target;
    };

    self.Message.extend({ trackMessage: 'xyx'})
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel(), $('#mydivhtml')[0]);
});
```

And also, you may want to update your knockout library if its still lesser than 3.2 for you to utilize `textInput` binding so you can change your html to this which is much simplier.

```
<div id="mydivhtml"> 
   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput:$root.Message"/>
</div>
```